How do I make a custom icon for a desktop shortcut
I'm sorry if this question has been asked, I am a new PC user and the only answers I could find related to themes and changing folder colors.
I set up this PC for my 7 year old who likes playing games like game builder garage and scratch. There are several websites I want him to use, such as khan academy and code.org etc, and I learned how to make shortcuts to them on the desktop using a text file. But I want to customize each of the links with their respective favicons. I assume I can also do this in the text file with some html.
Edit 1:
This is what I've got so far.
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=https://code.org/" />
    </head>
    <body> </body>
</html>

I also tried this in a desktop file, but it keeps saying there is an error opening the application. I guess it is a syntax issue because I was following ChatGPT's advice.
[desktop entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Code
Comment=Open code website
Exec=xdg-open https://code.org/
Icon=/home/myusername/documents/favicons/code.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application

Edit 2:
Regarding the desktop file, for the icon I did use my actual username and that file actually exists in that directory I didn't just copy paste from ChatGPT. I also made it executable by going into properties>permissions and checking allow executing as program. The image was originally .svg and I converted it to .png. Not only does it not open to the website, but it doesn't show the icon either.
When trying to open it from the terminal it says this:
./code.desktop: line 1: [desktop: command not found
./code.desktop: line 4: code: command not found
./code.desktop: line 5: https://code.org/: No such file or directory


Please [edit] your question and add an example text file you created to get a shortcut. Format the file contents as a code block, see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

This is the code.desktop file before editing.
[desktop entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Code
Comment=Open website
Encoding=UTF-8
URL=https://code.org/
Type=Link
Icon=home/myusername/Documents/favicons/code.ico
Terminal=false

Make the follow changes to code.desktop.

[Desktop Entry] marks the beginning of the file. Replace desktop entry with Desktop Entry.
Change home/myusername/Documents/favicons/code.ico to /home/myusername/Documents/favicons/code.ico to make it into a proper path.
Change URL=https://code.org/ back to an execute command: Exec=xdg-open https://code.org/
Replace Type=Link with Type=Application.

The edited code.desktop file should look like this.
[Desktop Entry] 
Version=1.0
Name=Code
Comment=Open website
Encoding=UTF-8
Exec=xdg-open https://code.org/
Type=Application
Icon=/home/myusername/Documents/favicons/code.ico
Terminal=false
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;


Go with the .desktop file, but don't list it as an application and correct the capitalization of [Desktop Entry]. This is what the file should look like:
[Desktop Entry] 
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Code.org
Comment=Open Code.org website
URL=https://code.org/
Type=Link
Icon=/home/myusername/Documents/favicons/code.ico
Categories=Development;WebDevelopment;Education;

Save it as a .desktop file on your desktop. It should be ready to go. If you're having an issue, use a .ico file for your icon instead of a .png.
For the reference of those interested, here's another working example of a shortcut that I actively use on my desktop:
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=DailyWrite
Type=Link
Categories=WordProcessor;ProjectManagement
URL=https://www.promptme.net/
Icon=/home/vin/Apps/DailyWrite/dailywrite.ico

Works every day.
